# Wrap React Application with IFrame - SEO?

Tags: seo

I have an application written in ReactJS which uses values from the URL to determine which content to render. My customers get their name in the URL and then their customized content is rendered (e.g. http://example.com/15secondadpro ). Now one of my customers requested an individual domain which I registered and referenced to my previously described domain.
(e.g. https://example2.com shows content of https://example.com/15secondadpro) When the customer now uses the domain and finds it e.g. at google it for sure just mimics my page and for that reason also show my html-meta-tags.

I currently think about make a individual index.html for the customer, add their meta-tags and then put my ReactJS-application in a Iframe to render the page. Is there a more elegant way or does the iframe would even have a bad impact on the search-engine ranks regarding the SEO topic?